# Mongoose (Typegoose) and RXJS

Tags: typescript, mongoose, rxjs

I am trying to convert the result of mongoose.Model.find(..) to an Observable using rxjs.from().

I am using Typegoose and I am no able to cast the result of .find to a Promise

```
MyClassModel.find({}) as Promise<MyClass>
```

I get TS error: 
Conversion of type 'DocumentQuery, InstanceType, {}>' to type 'Promise' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

and I cannot find the solution. I tried also:

```
MyClassModel.find({}) as Promise<DocumentQuery<InstanceType<MyCLass>, InstanceType<MyClass>>
```

But with no luck.

Anybody ever tried this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries are not promises. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises

They have `.then` functions but are not full promises. If you need a promise, call the `.exec` command.

```
MyClassModel.find({}).exec()
```